# Simple ember table header sort

Tags: sorting, ember.js, html-table

I have an ember application in which I have a table. I'm trying to do a simple column header sort but can't seem to get it to work or find any decent examples on how to do this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

links.hbs:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "linkID"}}>ID</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "name"}}>NAME</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "description"}}>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "url"}}>URL</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "effDate"}}>EFFECTIVE DATE</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "endDate"}}>END DATE</th>
        <th {{action "sortBy" "secr"}}>SECURITY RESOURCE</th>          
    <tr>
</thead>
```

links.js (controller):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions:{
            sortBy: function(property) {
                alert('Hello');
                this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
                this.set('sortAscending', !this.get('sortAscending'));
            }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are iterating over the `model` to build the table, the easiest way (with least amount of changes to your code) you could achieve this is just to set the `model` to [`arrangedContent`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_arrangedContent) each time you sort (when `sortedProperties` change):

**Controller:**

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    sortAscending: false,

    actions:{

        sortBy: function(property) {
            this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
            this.toggleProperty('sortAscending');
            this.set('model', this.get('arrangedContent'));  // set the model to the sorted array
        } 
    }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "linkID"}}>ID</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "name"}}>NAME</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "description"}}>DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "url"}}>URL</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "effDate"}}>EFFECTIVE DATE</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "endDate"}}>END DATE</th>
            <th {{action "sortBy" "secr"}}>SECURITY RESOURCE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each item in model}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.linkID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.url}}</td>
            <td>{{item.effDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.endDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.secr}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Here is a sample](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zonegirova/1/)**

**[Here is a full demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zonegirova/1/edit?html,js,output)**

If you need a custom comparator function (for example when comparing dates), you can override the [`sortFunction`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortFunction) hook and Ember will automatically call it when comparing elements for sorting. The parameters passed into `sortFunction` are the property values corresponding to the content of `sortProperties`.

For example, for array `[ {name: "bob"}, {name: "john"} ]` :

```
// ...
sortProperties: ['name'],
sortFunction: function(propA, propB) {
    // propA === "bob"
    // propB === "john"
    if (propA < propB) {  
        return -1;
    }
    if (propA > propB) {  
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // a must be equal to b
}
// ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot nem. I was not re-setting the model after performing the sort. This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple example for you here: http://jsbin.com/yilucefuwi/1/edit?html,js,output

Hard to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing your tbody and how you are assigning the array controller's content.
Are you sure your `#each` block is iterating through the **item controllers** and not directly the model?